# Alter menu link if logged in

Tags: hooks, navigation, redirection

I have a regular node in my main menu that:

1. if an anonymous user clicks on it, the node should be shown regularly
2. if a logged in user clicks on it, there should be a redirect to an external website

I tried

`HOOK_menu_link_alter` 
but that only is invoked on edit-and-save (if menu item is created via web)

`HOOK_node_view`
that seems to work but does not seem like a good solution to load the complete node and check for the user just to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the menu link per role (which is tricky considering the process with which menus are built and cached), I would suggest you go for adding redirects per role.

The [Url Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect) module should be able to help you achieve it.

> - Url Redirect is a simple, flexible module for allowing user(s) / role(s) to redirect from one
>     path to other.
> - Url Redirect is also handy to add / edit / delete url(s) , specify role(s) / user(s) for url
>     redirect, set a message for url redirect, enable / disable.